# Is there a way to get jena to read Json-ld into a model?

Tags: java, jena

I am not very experienced in a lot of the things im using here. This is for a school project where we are to build software that uses semantically structured data.

I am getting meteorological data from the Frost api (https://frost.met.no/)
in json-ld format. I want to read this into a Jena model. I am slightly confused whether jena supports this or not.

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //authentication for the frost api. I have a feeling i shouldn't share this online
        String auth = "######";

        // I use unirest to make the request to the api
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = null;
        try {
            response = Unirest.get("https://frost.met.no/sources/v0.jsonld?country=Norge").
                    basicAuth(auth, "").
                    asJson();
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get the data as string. Remove context tag as it gives an error:
        // "org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: loading remote context failed: https://frost.met.no/schema"
        // I'm assuming this is a problem on the api side. If anyone has any insights feel free to share
        String jsonString = response.getBody().toString();
        jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"@context\":\"https://frost.met.no/schema\",", "");

        // Print the json-ld string. Looks like it should.
        System.out.println(jsonString);

        //convert json-ld string into InputStream as is required by the read() function.
        InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes());
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel() ;

        try {
            model.read(targetStream, "", "JSON-LD") ;
        } catch (final Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        // Write model to console. This seems to output an empty model
        model.write(System.out, "JSON-LD");

    }
}
```

The response im getting looks something like this:

```
{
    "@context": "https://frost.met.no/schema",
    "@type": "SourceResponse",
    "apiVersion": "v0",
    "license": "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/no/",
    "createdAt": "2019-03-27T14:00:46Z",
    "queryTime": 0.534,
    "currentItemCount": 1685,
    "itemsPerPage": 1685,
    "offset": 0,
    "totalItemCount": 1685,
    "currentLink": "https://frost.met.no//auth//sources/v0.jsonld?country=Norge",
    "data": [
        {
            "@type": "SensorSystem",
            "id": "SN100",
            "name": "PLASSEN",
            "shortName": "Plassen",
            "country": "Norge",
            "countryCode": "NO",
            "geometry": {
                "@type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    12.5039,
                    61.1349
                ],
                "nearest": false
            },
```

There's a lot more but its just more data about different SensorSystems.

I get no errors, but the model it outputs seems to be empty:

```
{
  "@id" : "_:b0",
  "@type" : "file:///C:/Users/bm_93/Desktop/Fag/INFO216/SemesterOppgave/SourceResponse"
}
```

Am i doing it right? Is this supported in jena?

If not, is there anything i can do to get this json data into a jena model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jena supports JSON-LD reading and writing.

We can't look at the input that you're trying to read because it's behind a login, but in general if there is a `@context` link, then the parser needs to retrieve that context or else the JSON-LD won't be read correctly.

The URL of the context is `https://frost.met.no/schema`, but as far as I can tell, that is the URL of a web page and there is no JSON-LD context published there. So it looks like a problem with the Frost API.

You can always treat the response as normal JSON...

Comment: So the most likely reason its not working is because its lacking the @context ?
If i treat it as regular JSON is there a way i could use it to create a jena model without writing a manual parser?
I edited my original post to show some of what the response looks like.

Comment: That looks like the most likely reason. You could try to write your own context to define how the JSON keys map to RDF properties, but theme first thing to try is contact the people running that API and asking them how to get the context file because it doesn’t seem to be at the URL where the responses say it should be: